# Order of group with three generators

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

I am trying to work out all the elements of the group generated by three generators and just wanted to know how many elements I would find.

If I have a group $\langle x, y, z \rangle$ with $x^2, y^2$ and  $z^2$ equal to the identity, how many elements would this group generate?

Comment: Consider the elements $xy$, $(xy)^2$, ...

Comment: So your question is the specific case where $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = e$, right?

Comment: yes @MichaelTong

Comment: Possibly $8$, possibly infinitely many, possibly $4$.

Comment: Are these the only relations?

Comment: @G.Sass Also possibly $24$ or $48$.

Comment: Compare with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241051/group-generated-by-x-yx2-y2-1).

Comment: Finally, 120 is also possible. That covers all the (finite) Coxeter groups.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no more relations, the elements of the group are the words with letters $x,y,z$ with no consecutive, equal letters. Thus, the group is infinite.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if this was the intention of OP (they say "the group" and I think that might just be due to them not realizing that the result could depend on what additional structure we induce), but this is definitely the right answer in the other interpretation (what's the most general group we can make given just these requirements, which is obviously the free group)

Comment: @MichaelTong ANY free group on those three letters won't fulfill $\;x^2=y^2=z^2=1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant the natural free group-like construction under those constraints.